# SAS replace observations above a threshold in place

Tags: sas

I have a data set "test" like this:

```
OBJECTID    H1_UTIEF
259         15
261         2
262         15
264         10
479         20
564         20
```

I want to replace the observations in `H1_utiefe` by 0 if the value is above 15 (for example).

I tried:

```
data new;
set test;
if H1_utiefe <=15 then H1_utiefe = 0;
run;
```

But this just added a new colum named `H1_utiefe` with the value 0.

I tried with the modify statement, but didn't work out. 
Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: Your variable is called H1_UTIEF not H1_UTIEFE. That is your problem. Otherwise your data step statement is fine.

Comment: Your condition is backwards from what you said <= is less than, you want >=, greater than or equal to.